# WebStorm src folder is missing

Tags: webstorm

When I upgrade WebStorm to  2021.1.3, the `src` folder is missing:

[image]

When I open other projects, WebStorm also shows the `src` folder (Some projects work, some do not). Not sure if it's WebStorm's bug?

I double shift to find the `src` folder also shows nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I figure it out. After removing the `.idea` hidden folder (Jetbrains's config folder), it shows the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Directories and Add Content Root (your project folder).